# Use Diskshadow with Powershell

Tags: powershell

For a utility **diskpart**, Powershell allows me to pass data to the console 
by following

```
'list vol' | diskpart
```

very similar to the this, can we pass data to **diskshadow** utility ?

When i try, i get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\administrator> 'list vol' | diskshadow
Microsoft DiskShadow version 1.0
Copyright (C) 2007 Microsoft Corporation
On computer:  myserver,  11/8/2012 1:13:32 PM


**DISKSHADOW> Error reading from console. Win32 error: 0x6
The handle is invalid.**
```

Please suggest if i need to something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create a temp file with your command(s) and run `diskshadow` with that script.

```
$script = "./tmp.dsh"
"list shadows all" | Set-Content $script
diskshadow /s $script
Remove-Item $script
```

Comment: Because the author decided to not have it read commands from `STDIN`?

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the solution offered by Ansgar above and was banging my head trying to understand why Diskshadow ignores the content of my script and only returning this output:

```
Microsoft DiskShadow version 1.0
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation
On computer:  AS-C01-EX01,  12/2/2021 4:20:29 PM

->
```

Turns out that Diskshadow is sensitive to the script file encoding.

To solve this, I simply needed to set the encoding to ASCII using the -encoding parameter of Set-Content (or Out-File)